# Retrieving all children from a node Firebase-Android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase

I am new to Firebase
I have the following database

```
    -Root
         -IT
            -KOKlB####nryPhkTaA
                    -name: value
                    -location: value
                    -website: value
            -KOKlBBPh###nryPhkTaA
                    -name: value
                    -location: value
                    -website: value
         -Media
            -KOKlBBP##nryPhkTaA
                    -name: value
                    -location: value
                    -website: value
            -KOKlBBPhm##yPhkTaA
                     -name: value
                    -location: value
                    -website: value
```

The idea is I want to retrieve the children of each node to a listView
for ex: I have a list view each row contains the name, location and website of each company.

**This is how I push to database**

```
       public class Company {

private String name;
private String location;
private String website;

public Company(){}

public Company(String name,String location, String website)
{
    this.name=name;
    this.location=location;       
    this.website=website;     
}

     public Map<String, Object> toMap()
{
    HashMap<String, Object> result= new HashMap<>();
    result.put("name",name);
    result.put("location",location);
    result.put("website",website);

    return result;
}

     public void addNewCompany(String category,String name,String location, String website)
{
    Company company= new Company(name,location,city,website);
    String key= mRootRef.child("0").child(category).push().getKey();
    Map<String, Object> companyValues=company.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates=new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put("0/"+category+"/" + key,companyValues);

    mRootRef.updateChildren(childUpdates);

}
```

How I tried to retrieve

```
         DatabaseReference mConditionRef=mRootRef.child(category);
        mConditionRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                for (DataSnapshot dsp : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                CoLists.add(String.valueOf(dsp.getValue()));

                for(String data:CoLists){
                    mCompanies.add(data);
}
```

but this retrieve a list contains a whole of the data inside the category root..I want it to be a list of Company object.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use .getKey or .getValue() function of DataSnapshot to the required data.